# Error using ones Size inputs must be integers?

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, image-processing

hello every one i have a problem with my code for error

```
r =[zeros(size(img2,1),size(img2,2)) ones(size(img2,1),size(img2,2)/2)];
```

where `img2` an image of size `[111 235]`

```
Error using ones
Size inputs must be integers
```

and I want to have an image of the same size of `img2`

Comment: If `size(img2,2)` is an odd number (like in your example, `235`), then `size(img2,2)/2` is no integer, thus the error message.

Comment: To make an array of the same size as `img`, do `zeros(size(img))`. I don’t understand why you need the division by 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `size(img2,2)` is an odd number, so `size(img2,2)/2` is not an integer, hence the error message you get.

You need to think of what to do in those circumstances, either rounding it to the nearest integer, or adding/subtracting 1 before dividng by 2.